# How can I disable markdown on a string in a embed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that shows in an embed some files from a directory. The code works but in case of files with symbols in it, it modifies the text:
EX:
hello_world_-_1
BECOMES:
[image]

How can I solve this?

I don't even know what markdown this would be...

Comment: That seems more like a "how do I use Discord" question than a question about the computer programming side of things.

Comment: yeah, but I thought that there might be a way to disable markdown from the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't explicitly disable markdown, as the rendering happens client-side. The best you can do is wrap in triple backticks.

````
```hello_word_-_```
````

This will work unless your string contains triple backticks. And if you have a filename which contains triple backticks, then you have a different issue.

You could (and probably should) still check, of course. Just a simple "if filename contains ```` ``` ````", and you can report an error if it does.